# Getting errors for Password reset function in parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

I am programming an Android app that uses parse in the back end.

I am trying to implement a "Forgot Password" function. I used the Parse Documentation linked [here](https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#resetting-passwords).

So i added this to my app. i did a basic one with just the code to see if it works. but then i get this toast error.

"An appName, publicServerURL, and emailAdapter are required for password reset and email verification."

I am not sure exactly what the error is telling me since in the parse documentation it just says you need to pass the email string into the function and thats it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `appName`, `publicServerURL` and `emailAdapter` in your `index.js` for your Parse Server.

[This might help.](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server#email-verification-and-password-reset)

Comment: I am running the parse server through Amazon AWS. how would i be able to configure the servers settings?
I have tried to find the "index.js" on the server using putty but cant seem to find it.